# I get error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have following code and get TS2345 error. I have used Angular 7.

```
let totalAmount = quantity*rate;
let discountAmount = totalAmount - (totalAmount*discount)/100;
let finalValue = parseFloat(discountAmount - (discountAmount - (discountAmount * (100/(100+tax))))).toFixed(2).toString();
taxableAmount.setValue(finalValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you remove the `parseFloat`. [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) expects a string as the argument but you're passing a `number`,

```js
let totalAmount = quantity * rate;
let discountAmount = totalAmount - (totalAmount * discount) / 100;
let finalValue = (
  discountAmount -
  (discountAmount - discountAmount * (100 / (100 + tax)))
)
  .toFixed(2)
  .toString();
```

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAjgrghgOzASzATwgXggJgAwDcAUKJAE5xghYQCMhJ4EAJsgM4DGA9jEjXgDpaxUhDBwAHjXoimYLuOABBALY8+2WIhToIAKggUqsyK07qwqizXmKrvSAFoIACltxlah-pbtuDgEoIAHo6PAZRADNkBA8ANQ8YamwXIghfcwd7Pkc01zN-JGynDMLLLz4DF3o8ENcaiABqMUkAtqIAvIF5ADFkCRBmFxxO9O6uAGUwMhiAcxcA4iA)